# c# Asp creating custom routing engine

Tags: c#, asp.net

we have multiple Api projects on the same solution with different Areas 
and we have a startup project . we want to be able to catch the incoming request and decide which area to go .

Note : deciding which route to go will be based on a value in the request query string .

is there any way to accomplish this ?

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620149/reading-every-incoming-request-url-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @HamzaHaider this is talking about assigning a value from the incoming request and not picking up a controller for the request.